# Creating a query that will find out a price over $50 in clothing items

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I need help where I can create a qquery that will find out which clothing category has sold more than $50.
I have written this so far:

```
SELECT  
ITEM_TYPE.Description AS [Item Type Name], 
ITEM.ItemID * price AS [Total Spent]
FROM ITEM
INNER JOIN ITEM_TYPE ON ITEM.ItemTypeID = ITEM_TYPE.ItemTypeID
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEM ON ITEM.ItemID = ORDER_ITEM.ItemID
where ITEM_TYPE.Description Like '%Ladies%'
```

But the output should only display 1 row "Clothing Ladies" with a Total Sold of 80.50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `GROUP BY` clause and the aggregate function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT  
ITEM_TYPE.Description AS [Item Type Name], 
SUM(price) AS [Total Spent] -- ### apply SUM()
FROM ITEM
INNER JOIN ITEM_TYPE ON ITEM.ItemTypeID = ITEM_TYPE.ItemTypeID
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEM ON ITEM.ItemID = ORDER_ITEM.ItemID
where ITEM_TYPE.Description Like '%Ladies%'
GROUP BY ITEM_TYPE.Description -- ### add grouping for SUM()
```

I doubt you want to multiple the `price` by the Item's ID. If `price` is the *total* price for the line item, then just `SUM(price)` as above. If `price` is the item price, you probably want something like `SUM(price * quantity)`.

If you need to round the total to 2 decimal places, use `ROUND`:

```
ROUND(SUM(ITEM.ItemID * price), 2) AS [Total Spent] -- ### apply ROUND()
```

Comment: Thank you it work.  I just need to round the results to "80.50"

Comment: @jh86 are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jh86 see edited answer for how to round to 2 decimal places.

Comment: I tried this earlier and I get the same results.  It is not rounding the total sold

Comment: This is my output:
                           82514.00

Comment: @jh86 I just noticed a bug. You're multiplying `ITEM.ItemID` by `price`, which doesn't make sense. See edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you I finally have my output 80.50.

Answer (score 0):

You would do a SUM, which is an aggregate. When applying the aggregate you must group by any non-aggregate columns.  To filter on an aggregate you use HAVING to specify a condition for the SELECT. For example:

```
SELECT  
ITEM_TYPE.Description AS [Item Type Name], 
SUM(ITEM.ItemID * price) AS [Total Spent]  --aggregate column
FROM ITEM
INNER JOIN ITEM_TYPE ON ITEM.ItemTypeID = ITEM_TYPE.ItemTypeID
INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEM ON ITEM.ItemID = ORDER_ITEM.ItemID
where ITEM_TYPE.Description Like '%Ladies%'
GROUP BY ITEM_TYPE.Description        --GROUP BY the non aggregate columns
HAVING SUM(ITEM.ItemID * price) > 50  --HAVING filters the aggregate column
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to round to 80.5

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause. `GROUP BY` for group all rows with same description together, and `HAVING` for filter sum of prices more than 50.

```
SELECT  
    ITEM_TYPE.Description AS [Item Type Name], 
    SUM(ITEM.ItemID * price) AS [Total Spent]
FROM ITEM
    INNER JOIN ITEM_TYPE ON ITEM.ItemTypeID = ITEM_TYPE.ItemTypeID
    INNER JOIN ORDER_ITEM ON ITEM.ItemID = ORDER_ITEM.ItemID
WHERE ITEM_TYPE.Description Like '%Ladies%'
GROUP BY ITEM_TYPE.Description      
HAVING SUM(ITEM.ItemID * price) > 50
```

for a better understanding of having and group by clause you care to read more about them https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp